# Flagging very recent answers VLQ

Tags: discussion

What's the ELU position on flagging very recent low quality answers?

When I use the review queue for first posts there are a lot of very low quality posts. Sometimes other users have already commented on the post along the usual lines, *welcome, add some sources, etc...*

Let's assume the post itself is very low quality in its current state and an hour old and the comment is half an hour old, so both pretty recent. Am I supposed to purely act the current state of the post? I.e. flag VLQ and move on or is there a general policy that I should skip it to give the user time to improve the answer? I assume that the latter possibility will just make it pop up in someone else's review queue, which increases the overall review effort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Am I supposed to act purely on the current state of the post?

I act on the post's current state. I choose whether to comment, edit, flag, vote or simply move on, and I act quickly. If someone edits it later, the post will be cleared from the VLQ review queue.

It's worth noting that VLQ flag option for a post is automatically disabled after 7 days, or if somebody upvotes it.

> If you comment on a first answer, do you simultaneously flag it as VLQ?

I don't usually take more than one action on a First Post.

> So if there is a one liner with just a word, that would fit, but there are no sources. Do you flag VLQ or do you write a comment suggesting to add something and welcome the new user? Both seems appropriate.

If I have time on my hands, I'd edit it myself, or leave a comment. Else, I'd downvote it, or flag it as VLQ.

Comment: I removed my comments since you incorporated them in your answer.